# Rails form builder - how to pass a user object to edit_password_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page with a  form to update a user. What I want  is to have a link inside that points to a `edit_password_path`so the user will be redirected to a page to update their password.

How do I pass the user information inside my user form to `edit_password_path` so my `PasswordController` knows which user the `edit_password_path` is for?

My form inside my **users/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= f.label(:first_name, "First Name:") %>
        <%= f.text_field(:first_name) %>
        …
        …
        <%= link_to("Update Your Password", edit_password_path) %>
        …
<% end %>
```

Comment: If your passwordcontroller#edit & routes accepts a user then you might be able to use `edit_password_path(@user)`?

Comment: @Marcus In terms of `routes.rb` and inside my controller, how do I allow the `edit` action take in a user?

Comment: this guide is great to get the basic understanding of how routing work. Among the first examples you'll find the answer you're looking for. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-purpose-of-the-rails-router

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working by adding this to my routes.rb `get /password/:id/, to: password#edit, as: edit_password`. But what I don't understand is that, I have to add `as: edit_password` in that line. Otherwise, without `as: edit_password`, I can't reference `edit_password_path` in my view files. Why is that?

Comment: `as:` helps you name you route so you can use the url/path helpers (like you do). You can run `rake routes` to see all routes that are available, where they lead and if they have an associated name

Comment: By omitting the `as:` part and just having `get /password/:id/, to: password#edit`, when I run `rake routes` I'm about to see edit_password. But I still can't all `edit_password_path`. Does that mean `as:` is required whenever I do `get route, to: action`?

Comment: It shouldn't be required. Is the `edit_password` associated with `password#edit` when you raked the routes? Else it might be that you have an old route with the same name from before that you override when you name it with `as:`

Answer (score 0):

`edit_password_path(@user)` or `edit_password_path(current_user)` for `Devise`

in `routes.rb` you should have:

```
 resources :users
```

this will give you by default routes for `index`, `edit`, `update`, `new`, `show`, `create` and `destroy` actions.